# Hide overflow of div beyond end of page

Tags: html, css

I have some divs that contain an image.
They are positioned throughout a regular html page like this...

```
<div class="img1"><img src="img.png"></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="img.png"></div>
```

And the corresponding css to place them....

```
.img1 {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -500px;
  top: 1000px;
}

.img2 {
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
  top: 2400px;
}
```

The problem I have, is when certain pages are shorter than the lowest positioned image div, the browser renders everything. Usually I'd drop in overflow:hidden, but this doesn't wrok.

Is there a trick to making sure the page ends where the content ends and NOT where the img div ends?

[image]

Comment: If you can provide more code or a front-end that would be great. However, I would try `overflow: hidden;` on your `.img2`

Comment: Solved this by wrapping the entire page in a new div and giving that a value of overflow:hidden